Why check both req.isAuthenticated() and req.user in Passport Oauth 2.0 authentication?
Why check both req.isAuthenticated() & req.user for authentication in Passport Oauth 2.0? I believe req.isAuthenticated() alone is enough for social sign-in. I see others using both, but I don't understand why. What's the best practice here?
I believe req.isAuthenticated() alone is enough

.isAuthenticated() is better, because passport allow you to redefine property name to store user.
app.use(passport.initialize({ userProperty: 'me' }))

now req.me should be used to access current user info, not req.user
Lets check the source code of the .isAuthenticated().  As you can see, it literally checks if property where the user information is stored is present in the request (this[property]) ? true : false;
